# Why is the HanYu Pinyin entry method for 亅 "jue3" instead of "jue2"?

Tags: input-methods

Why does the Windows 10 HanYu Pinyin entry method for the 亅 (hook radical) character require typing "jue3" (juĕ) instead of "jue2" (jué)?

The pronunciations at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%85), [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BA%85), and [漢典](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E85.htm) are "jué", so the discrepancy doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps you should switch your IME - 搜狗输入法 is definitely the most popular

Comment: Software mistakes and bugs are common. It is hard to guess how it ends up there. The Unihan database （http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E4%BA%85）also has the pinyin as jué, which references a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This character is not often used in China. As a Chinese person, I don't know the character until I searched it on the internet. The electric dictionary says it should be jue(3).  At last, I have to say I really didn't recognize the character. If we want to express the word "hook ", we would directly use 勾子 instead of jue (3). Hope I did help you.[image]

Comment: Your pictures show the pinyin jue2, but you saying jue3 in your post, why?

Answer (score 0):

I have referenced to many online Chinese Dictionaries,

basically it is "jue2" (jué), not "jue3" (juĕ).

May be the programmer or editor of the HanYu Pinyin entry method is confused by the Cantonese:

Refer to:
[CANTONESE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%85#Pronunciation)

because the pronunciation of 亅 in Cantonese is kyut**3**

I hope I did answer your question.